# Command with infinite coordnates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a command that is `/execute @e[type=Snowball] -603 4 170 /summon PrimedTnt` So whenever I throw a snowball at the specific coordnates, it will blow up. Is there a way to make it so there are infinite coords so no matter where the snowball lands it blows up no matter what? 
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You're misunderstanding the purpose of the coordinates a little bit. The command as you have it will summon a primed TNT at `-603 4 170` for every snowball. No matter where those snowballs are in the world, that is where the TNT will go.

What you'll want to do is use tilde notation to specify relative coordinates:

```
/execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ summon PrimedTnt
```

What this will do is summon primed TNT at the coordinates of every snowball entity. Be careful about putting this in a clock without some sort of `/kill @e[type=Snowball]` command, unless you *want* to have TNT summoned along the entire trajectory of the snowball.

Comment: Ok Thanks! Yes I know what you mean I already put that command into a command block next to a repeater the '/kill @e[type=Snowball]'

Comment: how would you set it up then? i mean the full redstone and stuff

Comment: I did /testfor @e[type=Snowball] comparator 5 ticks then I did the execute command and then I connected a repeater to that and did /kill @e[type=Snowball]