# Snowballs exploding like TNT?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've been playing Minecraft on a server and I was using snowballs for fun. I'm not sure what happened, if it's a plugin, command or something else. The snowballs are exploding like TNT after they're shot! They also have the animation and effects of being lit on fire like a thrown Ender Charge. Why is this happening? [image: It's so strange]

[image: Same id and everything]

Comment: In order to better assist you we must first have way more info.  What is the version the server is running, what mods are you using?  So until then you'll get down voted and flagged as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I have this funny feeling...  wasn't there a question recently where a server owner was asking how to make snowballs explode like TNT on his server?  How much do you want to bet it's the *same* server?

Comment: found it http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192100/command-with-infinite-coordnates

Answer (score 3):

The server could be doing this in a number of ways. It could be using a custom Bukkit plugin, or it could be using a command block sequence.

If you want to do this in your world, you can with command blocks. Put the command `execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ summon Fireball ~ ~ ~` on a clock, preferably a fill or setblock clock. Any snowballs in the world, wether thrown or dispensed, will be turned into fireballs. However, this won't apply to dropped items snowballs.